# Identical UPDATE query. One works the other doesn't

Tags: vba, ms-access

Trying to update a table using the UPDATE query which it gets from different Recordsets. One UPDATE query runs and updates the records but the other runs, doesn't update the records and doesn't throws any error where the problem is. I suspect it's somewhere in the WHERE clause but can't pinpoint.

I played around with the quotation marks but no luck and this is where I am confused the most about. Single, Double quotes and `&` character are a bit confusing for me.

```
extArea_SQL = "SELECT * FROM Area;"
Set rsArea = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(extArea_SQL, dbOpenDynaset)
extDiscipline_SQL = "SELECT * FROM Disciplines;"
Set rsDisp = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(extDiscipline_SQL, dbOpenDynaset)

instAreaName_SQL = "UPDATE ReportGen SET ReportGen.AreaName = '" & rsArea.Fields("AreaName") & "' WHERE ReportGen.AreaID = '" & rsArea.Fields("AreaID") & "';"
updtDispName_SQL = "UPDATE ReportGen SET ReportGen.DisciplineName = '" & rsDisp.Fields("DisciplineName") & "' WHERE ReportGen.DisciplineID = '" & rsDisp.Fields("DisciplineID") & "';"

db.Execute instAreaName_SQL, dbFailOnError
db.Execute updtDispName_SQL, dbFailOnError
```

I'd also like to point out that AreaName and the Discipline data are string and has special characters like `-,()/` etc.

Not sure what I am doing wrong with the lower (updtDispName_SQL) UPDATE query where as the one above works with no problems. I copy pasted the format of the one working and made changes to the lower one but still can't point out.

Can any one point out what I am missing out here?

Comment: My guess is that somewhere you are picking up a number from one place and a string from another and that is causing an issue with the update based on the data types in that field in the table.

Comment: @Karlomanio I did double check the data types. The fields are all set to Short text. Do you think Input mask could be the issue? But for these data I am pretty sure they are normal strings and saved as default short text that access has.

Comment: I cannot see that there is one here, but since you are asking about it, I assume there is one. It is possible that the input mask could cause that problem. I'm still thinking there may be some data that is coerced into a data type you don't intend it to be when the update occurs.  The same behavior could happen with an input mask.

Comment: Examine the SQL statement text contained in `updtDispName_SQL` immediately before you execute it.  Perhaps it does not contain what you expect.  You can also test by pasting it into SQL View of a new query in the Access query designer.  When you run it from there, does Access give you any clues as to why it doesn't do what you expect?

Comment: If you have `DoCmd.SetWarnings False` anywhere in your project's code, you should do `DoCmd.SetWarnings True` at least until you have sorted the problem.

Comment: @HansUp Oh I tried it in the query wizard and it throws up Enter Parameter value.. Maybe thats why it is not working. But not sure what it is and why it is coming up. Any clues?

Comment: The parameter input box shows you the name of whatever Access thinks is a parameter.  In many cases, that is a misspelled field name.  What does it show you?

Comment: @HansUp Enter Parameter Value for Disciplines.DisciplineName and the same for DisciplineID

Comment: How can that be?  You're attempting `UPDATE ReportGen`  So  why does `Disciplines.DisciplineName` get included in the SQL statement?  Please show us the text of the SQL statement which triggers that "Enter Parameter Value" event.

Comment: UPDATE ReportGen SET ReportGen.DisciplineName = Disciplines.DisciplineName WHERE ReportGen.DisciplineID = Discipline.DisciplineID;

Comment: The VBA code in your question adds single quotes; there are no single quotes in the `UPDATE` in your comment.  It had to have come from somewhere else.  I can't help you.

Comment: @HansUp Sorry I didn't understand. What single quotes are you referring to?

Comment: Your query does not make any joins nor does it have any subqueries. Looks like invalid SQL to me. See the answer below for more help./

Answer (score 1):

Consider pure SQL without recordsets as Access supports `JOIN` or subqueries in `UPDATE`. Save below as stored queries and run as needed with GUI or VBA. Unlike your code which did not loop and would only run on current recordset row (not necessarily the first), below queries run on all matched rows.

**SQL**

Query 1

```sql
UPDATE ReportGen r
INNER JOIN Area a
  ON r.AreaID = a.AreaID
SET r.AreaName = a.AreaName;
```

Query 2

```sql
UPDATE ReportGen r
INNER JOIN Disciplines d
   ON r.DisciplineID = d.DisciplineID
SET r.DisciplineName = d.DisciplineName;
```

**VBA**

```vb
'DOES NOT SHOW WARNINGS
CurrentDb.Execute "mySavedUpdateQuery"

'DOES SHOW WARNINGS (NO NEED TO CLOSE ACTION QUERIES)
DoCmd.OpenQuery "mySavedUpdateQuery"
```